# Redirect Causes Missing Images

Tags: images, redirect

I recently built a new internal network using WordPress called inSite. Our staff can access it just by typing in `insite` in their web browsers or by typing in the complete address: `insite.foo.edu` while connected to our network or on our VPN. The General settings of the WP install are set as follows:

```
WordPress Address (URL): http://insite
Site Address (URL): http://insite
```

We just launched the site last week and all is good as long as you only type in `insite`, but if the full address is typed in all the icons are missing and replaced with garbled text and a form doesn't work on the home page. If you click on any other page (for instance Forms which takes you to `insite/forms/`, everything is fine and shows up, and if you click back to the home page where it was messed up, it is now correct and the address is just `insite`.

So as long as you only type in `insite` or `insite/foo/` everything is fine, but if you use the full address `insite.foo.edu` to the site or any of the pages the icons are missing and forms don't work but everything else is there.

So I don't know if this has to do with what I have as the WP Address URL or Site Address URL in the General Settings or something else?? What do I check...how do I fix?

Also, I don't know if this has anything to do with the issue, but our IT department redirected `intranet` to `insite.foo.edu` when any of our browsers are opened initially. This is the way it was before only it went to `intranet` Now the browser shows `intranet` initially and redirects to the full address of `insite`.

I just cannot figure out what would cause the icons to be missing/forms don't work but all information, page structure and everything else is there and fine just by using the alternate address. Any thoughts or help would be appreciative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this site only used on your internal network? If so you could set up a 301 redirect which would automatically replace the insite.xxx.edu url with the insite address.

Comment: Yes, it is only used internally as our intranet. I know our IT dept has set up some redirect so will me doing a 301 cause any other issues? But my main concern is WHY things aren't working when you go to the full address? I've never had this issue in the 10 years building WP sites so it bothers me, LOL

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jazibobs. I set up a 301 redirect and that worked for the home page...my only concern now is if anyone happen to have bookmarked a page that used the entire address. I guess I'll find out if there are any issues.

Comment: Well the beauty of a 301 is that it's forever. Even if they have the old address bookmarked the server will redirect them to the new url every time :)